# Classic Bluetooth communication (RFCOMM) in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, bluetooth, serial-communication, rfcomm

I am looking for Classic Bluetooth communication (RFCOMM)/ serial port communication using classic Bluetooth and not Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) in Xamarin.Forms preferably. I have some emulator which is hosted on a com port and a Bluetooth adaptor. I want to connect to that Bluetooth adaptor and fetch/read data in my mobile app.

[image: This is DPIR emulator which writes the data on a com port.]

[image: This is Odorator2 emulator reads the data.]

I had explored Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) using ble.net plugin but I need to connect to a port i.e. Bluetooth SPP and read data in the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no classic Bluetooth communication APIs in Xamarin.forms. You would have to use the UWP built-in [Bluetooth RFCOMM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm) APIs to communicate.

You could check the [Bluetooth RFCOMM chat sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat) to learn how to use these APIs.